# Class instantiation Syntax - Can't understand it

Tags: php

I am New to PHP and reading these day "PHP in Action" book
is good. But what i don't understand is its Class Initiation syntax.

it uses often a syntax like

```
$config = new Config;
```

can someone please explain why he is  instantiating like this, i mean without parentheses?

And is there are goog PHP book available to learn OOP with assignments?

Comment: your question signals to me that you're new to programming, and yet  you're learning fast. is that right?

Comment: You are right. Can you please suggest me a book for MVC?

Comment: since you're new to programming, there's a risk that you'll learn the wrong things. especially if you're using php to learn from, since many of the php guides around the internet use dangerous short cuts that the language provides. i haven't heard of any book for php that teaches mvc. however, i think you should take a look at java when it comes to learning oop. after all, php oop and java oop are not that different. i would recommend these two books: http://goo.gl/TqC4k (basics of oop) http://goo.gl/3eh1R (advanced oop). after reading those, mvc will not be a problem to understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PHP` isn't the only language that supports this. If the constructor takes no parameters, also `C++` allows the bypass of parentheses.

Choose whichever you see around the code - i.e. if the company leaves out parentheses for default constructors, you should also leave them out, and vice-versa. Both are legal.